# pydev project - no module named pyodbc

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pyodbc

Hello guys I am pretty new to all this so please bear with me. I am trying to execute the following python code on eclipse but finding some errors:

```
import pyodbc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I get the following error for both:

```
import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
   import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
```

When going to command prompt and clicking on `pip install pyodbc` I get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in c:\users\sammy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

What should I do? Many thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what Anaconda is, but I don't think it's the same as pip. Isn't there a `conda` installer of some sort?. Anyway, this is environmental. Whatever Python you are running is not using or able to find where thos modules are placed. You should review what version of Pyhton, what "anaconda3" has to do with it, and what pip thinks it is doing. My guess is that the python that you are running is from befoer you installed Anaconda. e.g., this might get you started: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/lnpJDf6Nx18

Comment: @jdv thanks for fast reply. Anaconda is a way to write python on windows. I wrote "conda install pyodbc" as of the link you shared and it says all requested packages already installed. Any other option in mind?

Comment: Well, however you are running the example code at the top of your question is probably unrelated to the `conda` or `pip` commands you run later. That is, I suspect you already had Python installed. It could be as easy as checking your PATH, but we don't know enough to help. Check how you are running these commands (from an application? from the command line?) and verify that you are running what you think you are.

Comment: Have you set an interpreter for your project? If yes, then look on this page for "Forced Buildin" and add pyodbc there: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html. If no, follow the instructions and add the interpreter. This basically tells PyDev where Anaconda is.

Comment: I would highly recommend learning about virtualenvs and using them, regardless of your IDE. It'll save you headaches later! Here's a basic tutorial I think will help you quite a bit: http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/eclipse-pydev-and-virtualenv

Comment: @jdv I am using eclipse and running that path from it. How can I check my path?

Comment: @Joe is eclipse considered my interpreter?

Comment: @FlipperPA thanks! Will look into it

Comment: @sam I presume you have some sort of python/pydev plugin in Eclipse where you can inspect settings via Preferences. Or maybe this is a Run Configuration. Again, this is highly environmental, and there is limited help we can offer given what we have. This isn't coding question anymore; it's a "how do I get my IDE and Python environment to agree" question.

Comment: @jdv ok thanks! Any idea how I can get them to agree? Or any link where I can start from?

Comment: Oh, I see. PyDev is an Eclipse customization. I'd start with the docs for PyDev, assuming that is what you are using. Note the comment above by @Joe

Comment: In your case Anaconda would be considered your interpreter. If it is available in the system environment variables PyDev should find it. Else you can point PyDev to it. Eclipse - Preferences - PyDev - Python Interpreter

Comment: @Joe saves the day! I had to do the same "pip install ___" but through eclipse and not the cmd prompt.. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are on eclipse just go to here ,

```
windows->preferences->python interpreter->select path of your python interpreter
```

[image]
Now Click on button install/uninstall with pip and type pyodbc there as shown in pic 2 [image: pic 2] . Now click on Run . Then restart your eclipse again . It should solve your issue.